# How to have a result array when using autocomplete in Angular 6

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, autocomplete

I want to create a array with id of products.

I have this form:

```
this.myform= new FormGroup({
  'products_id': this.fb.array([], Validators.required),
  'unit_price': new FormControl('', [Validators.required)
});
```

My function submit is:

```
  onAddProducts() {
    this.areWeWaiting = true;
    let newp = this.myform.value
    let newprod= new Products(
      newp
    );
    this.ws.createP(newprod).subscribe(
      result => {
        if (result === true) {
        } else {
          this.areWeWaiting = false;
        }
      },
      error => {
        this.areWeWaiting = false;
      }
    );
  }
```

Result from this code is this array: `["Y4FQS", "qOKTN", "sRm54"]`

I want to have a result like this:  `["1", "2", "3"]` I want to submit Id of product, not name of product.

For this I try to change my code like this:

I declare a property   `prodId: Array<string>[];` and in function submit:

```
 onAddProducts() {
    this.areWeWaiting = true;
    let newp = this.myform.value
    newp.products_id= this.prodId;
    let newprod= new Products(
      newp
    ); ........}
```

This prodId I take form this function:

```
  updateForm(ev: any, idd: any, componentid: any) {
    if (ev.isUserInput) {
      if (componentid === 'products_id') {
        this.prodId = idd;
         this.myForm['controls']['products_id'].setValue(ev.source.value);
      } else {
        console.log('ooops');
      }
    }
  }
```

This is a function that get all product from API:

```
    this.ws.getAllproducts().subscribe(
      products=> {
        this.products= products.map((prod) => {
          this.filteredProducts = this.myForm.controls['products_id'].valueChanges
            .pipe(
              startWith(''),
              map(value => this._filters(value))
            );
          return new Products(prod);

        });
      }
    );
```

this function return:

```
{
    "StatusCode": 0,
    "StatusMessage": "OK",
    "StatusDescription": [
        {
            "products_id": "1",
            "products_name": "PkMGo",
            "unit_price": 100,
        },
        {
            "products_id": "2",
            "products_name": "Y4FQS",
            "unit_price": 100,
        },
        {
            "products_id": "3",
            "products_name": "Mlld0",
            "unit_price": 100,
        },
        {
            "products_id": "4",
            "products_name": "q0KTN",
            "unit_price": 100,
        },...
   ]
}
```

This code show me only id of the latest product like `"3"`

Can you ask me any idea please, how to post an array like `["1", "2", "3"]`

Thank you!

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. I'm having some trouble understanding the relationships in your data. Could you maybe add some example data to show what you would expect `myform` to contain?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I edit my post, also please, can you see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52757862/autocomplete-display-id-product-using-angular6

Comment: That's the result form the web service? In `myform` your field `products_id` is an array. Should that only contain the ID values themselves (like `['1', '2', '3']`) or entire objects, like you showed in the update?

Comment: From ws get this json, I select some product and post to ws with an array. Please look this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52757862/autocomplete-display-id-product-using-angular6 I solution this error, but I have anther problem

Comment: This is demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zvgf5f-pm5eqd?file=main.ts

Comment: Have you any idea please?

Comment: Hi, I'll get to it soon. Just handling a crisis first.