# autocomplete display id_product using Angular6

Tags: angular, forms, typescript, autocomplete

Next to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52756080/how-to-have-a-result-array-when-using-autocomplete-in-angular-6) post I can post this result ["1", "2", "3"] but I have another problem.

When I select product, in view show id, 1, 2 and 3, not name of product. like in [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pqSbw.jpg)

I change function `updateForm()` like below:

```
products: Products[] = []; 

 updateForm(ev: any, idd: any, componentid: any) {
    if (ev.isUserInput) {
      if (componentid === 'products_name') {
      this.prodId = idd;
      for (let i = 0; i < this.products.length; i++) {
      if (this.products[i].products_id=== idd) {
      console.log(this.products[i].products_name) //in this part I can see product name
    this.myForm.controls.products_id.setValue(this.products[i].products_name)
          }
        }
      } else {
        console.log('error');
      }
    }
  }
```

And my html code is Like this:

```
  <div class="row">
    <div class="input-field col s10">
      <div class="form-group">
        <div formArrayName="products_id">
          <div *ngFor="let p of myForm.get('products_id').value; let i = index">
            <input  formControlName="{{i}}" id="products_id" type="text"  aria-label="Number" matInput
              [matAutocomplete]="auto">
            <mat-autocomplete autoActiveFirstOption #auto="matAutocomplete" [displayWith]="displayWith">
              <mat-option (onSelectionChange)="updateForm($event, pro.products_id, 'products_name')" *ngFor="let pro of filteredProduct | async"
                [value]="pro.products_id">
                {{pro.products_name}} 
              </mat-option>
            </mat-autocomplete>
            <div class="button-left">
                <button *ngIf="myForm.controls.products_id.value.length > 1" type="button" class="fa" (click)="onRemoveItem(i)">-</button>
              </div>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="input-field col s2">
      <button type="button" class="btn" (click)="onAddItem()">+</button>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Any idea please? How to display products_name ?

Thank you!

Comment: Do you have this on [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/fork/angular) ?

Comment: This is demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zvgf5f-gcwdf5?file=app/autocomplete-overview-example.html  The problem is:  when I select product in + second, in view show id_product, not name of product.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zvgf5f-pm5eqd?file=main.ts this is

Comment: Have you any idea please?

Comment: I've added my answer. Please check if that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was an issue with your Template and with your `updateFormProducts` method.

Here are the fixes:

```
updateFormProducts(ev: any, idd: any, componentid: any, index) {
  console.log(ev.source.viewValue)
  console.log(componentid)
  if (ev.isUserInput) {
    if (componentid === 'products_id') {
      console.log(ev.source.viewValue);
      ( < FormArray > this.myform.get('products_id')).at(index).patchValue(ev.source.viewValue);
    } else {
      console.log('error');
    }
  }
}
```

In this method, you'll need to pass index of the State field in your `FormArray` and then call `patchValue` on only that field which you'll be able to get using `(<FormArray>this.myform.get('products_id')).at(index)`

Then in your template, you also need to fix a few things. Here's your updated template:

```
<form [formGroup]="myform" (ngSubmit)="onAddprod()" class="example-form">
  <div class="form-group">
    <div formArrayName="products_id">
      <div *ngFor="let s of myform.get('products_id').controls; let i = index">
        <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
          <input [formControlName]="i" matInput placeholder="State" aria-label="State" [matAutocomplete]="auto">

          <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" [displayWith]="displayWith">
            <mat-option *ngFor="let state of filteredStates | async" (onSelectionChange)="updateFormProducts($event, state.products_name, 'products_id', i)" [value]="state.products_id">
              <span>{{state.products_name}}</span>
            </mat-option>
          </mat-autocomplete>

        </mat-form-field>
      </div>
      <div class="input-field col s2">
        <button type="button" class="btn" (click)="onAddItem()">+</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <br>
  
  <div class="input-field col s2">
    <input formControlName="unit_price" id="unit_price" type="text">
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn waves-effect waves-light">Register</button>
</form>
```

Here's an [**Updated StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-auto-complete-eg) for your ref.

## UPDATE

For your issue, you might want to do this:

In template create a `getter`:

```
get productIdFormArray () {
  return (<FormArray>this.myform.get('products_id')).controls;
}
```

And in the template, you can use `productIdFormArray` to iterate over through the `FormArray`:

```
...
<div *ngFor="let s of productIdFormArray; let i = index">
  <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
...
```

You can find the changes in the Updated StackBlitz as well.

Comment: StcakBlitz isn't updated. Please can you post it. Thank you so much. I try now.

Comment: When I run `ng build --prod` show this error `Property 'controls' does not exist on type 'AbstractControl'.` in this     `<div *ngFor="let s of myform.get('products_id').controls; let i = index">`

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Dear SiddAjmera, I try also to put `[formControl]="stateCtrl"` in Input because filter doesn't work. Demo work  like this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-auto-complete-eg-dxq2ve?file=app/autocomplete-overview-example.html

Comment: What exactly do you want? I thought you wanted to show the State String instead of its index. And why exactly do you want to use the `[formControl]="stateCtrl"`?

Comment: Yes I want to show string, its okay this part. But  also I want to search. I use `[formControl]="stateCtrl"` because autocomplete work with this formControl.

Comment: When I change `filteredState` like this     `this.filteredStates = this.myform.controls['products_id'].valueChanges.pipe(startWith(''),        map(state =>  this._filterStates(state)));` work good only in first input. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-auto-complete-eg-5gv1gf?file=app/autocomplete-overview-example.ts

Comment: Hello, can you help me please, I have a problem in this demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-g2hcvs-wauvmk?file=app/autocomplete-overview-example.ts   I want to show name city in view, and post id_city. This demo works, but if I remove or add items , patchform doesn't work. My post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52875979/patch-form-doesnt-work-well-using-angular-6