# Patch form doesn't work well using Angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript, autocomplete

can you ask me any idea please, I have a problem in this [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-g2hcvs-wauvmk?file=app/autocomplete-overview-example.ts)
I want to show name city in view, and post id_city. This demo works, but if I remove or add items this patch form doesn't work.

I have this control:

```
city_id: this.client.forEach(x => {

  x.city_id.forEach(cid => {
    //this.formData.push(new FormControl(x.city_id))
    let control = new FormControl(cid, Validators.required);
    (<FormArray>this.myform.controls['city_id']).push(control);

    setTimeout(()=>{
      let cityName = this.city.find(c=> c.city_id == cid).name;
      control.patchValue(cityName, {onlySelf: true, emitEvent:true});
    },100)
  });

})
```

Comment: Sorry but I didn't quite get what you're trying to achieve here.

Comment: Please, look demo. I want to post only id_city when I add, remove items. This patchform dosen't work good. When I add ore remove item, I register name of city.

Comment: Ill suggest you to first trim some things out of your code, and clean it up a little bit.

Answer (score 0):

Just change tis:

```
(onSelectionChange)="updateFormProducts($event, item.name, 'city_id', i)"
```

To this:

```
(onSelectionChange)="updateFormProducts($event, item.city_id, 'city_id', i)"
```

Comment: Nothing happens. When I add new items, I submit name `city_id: Array[3] 0: "Mlld0"
1: "q0KTN"
2: "4"`

Comment: Or, can you see this demo, https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-g2hcvs-dauesh?file=app/autocomplete-overview-example.ts   I want to show in autocomplete name of city, and id of city I want to save.Thank you!